# How to rescale differences in time in R?

Tags: r, time

I often want to compute how long an algorithm might take till completion. I take a snapshot of start time with `.Sys.time()` and a time stamp after completion of part of the task (repetitions). Then I scale this up by dividing by completed tasks and multiplying by remaining tasks. However, then the unit of the time variable does not change. If it is in seconds, for example it will remain in this unit even after multiplying it by any scalar. This causes two problems:

1. The multiplied number is still in the unit of the original difference, which may be too large to be interpreted (e.g. seconds)
2. After rescaling the number (e.g. divide by 60) the scale of the time variable is not changed (e.g. still indicating seconds)

I want to change the scale of the sime difference after rescaling to any time measurement needed (seconds, minutes, hours, days).

An example (sorry the speed may vary by machine):

```
set.seed(12345)
j=0
s = Sys.time()
while(i == 0){
  i = sample(x=c(0,1),size=1,replace=TRUE,prob=c(1-10^-6,10^-6) )
  j = j+1
}
e = Sys.time()

dif = (e-s)
```

On my machine:

```
> dif
Time difference of 0.04200912 secs
```

Now assume the task has to be executed another `10E5` times.

```
> dif*10^5
Time difference of 4200.912 secs
```

Which is still on the unit of the original scale. How do I transfer `dif` now into minutes or hours? The following is misleading.

```
> dif*10^5/60
Time difference of 70.01519 secs
```

Comment: look at `?difftime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `difftime` to obtain time difference because it allows you to specify the units. Just subtracting two times may not always give the difference in the same unit. Compare these two cases

```
a = structure(1506077762.63353, tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
b = structure(1505577762.63353, tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
a - b
#Time difference of 5.787037 days

x = structure(1506078155.6917, tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
y = structure(1506077155.6917, tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
x - y
#Time difference of 16.66667 mins
```

As for rescaling, you could either use `seconds_to_period` function of `lubridate` package

```
#DATA
s = Sys.time()
Sys.sleep(4)
e = Sys.time()
dif = difftime(time1 = e, time2 = s, units = "secs")
dif
#Time difference of 4.045822 secs

library(lubridate)
seconds_to_period(round(dif*1e5, 0))
#[1] "4d 16H 23M 2S"
```

Or you can also use `difftime` of base R

```
difftime(time1= as.POSIXct(as.numeric(dif*1e5), origin = "1970-01-01 00:00:00", tz = "UTC"),
         time2= as.POSIXct("1970-01-01 00:00:00", tz = "UTC"),
         units= "hours")
#Time difference of 112.3839 hours
```

Comment: Thanks, `seconds_to_period` is very useful. The only strange thing is the rather high number of digits in seconds.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for.